# Enumerating Pseudo-Documents in a Shallow Firestore Collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database with documents `/users/{userId}/public/doc`, but the pseudo-document `users/{userId}` actually has no fields of its own. In the web-based firebase console, these pseudo-documents list - but are shown gray-out in an italic font, probably to signify that they are missing.

However, I'm unable to list these pseudo-documents programmatically either through Python's `firebase_admin`, or firebase CLI tools.

So, how can you actually list items in shallow collections?

Comment: As / public is already a subcollection, and in the document {userid} you have no data, it is that the collection 'user' as it does not exist, to understand this behavior I recommend this article. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

Comment: @TomaszVizaint, Yeah, I get that. But I don't want to delete the users, I want to list them. And since the website can do it somehow, it must be doable in theory...

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that the Firebase console does not necessarily have to use the operations provided by the public javascript client SDK to populate its screen.  For example, it could be calling out to a backend that uses the nodejs (or equivalent) SDK that provides a [listDocuments()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#listDocuments) API that:

> Retrieves the list of documents in this collection.
>
> **The document references returned may include references to "missing
> documents", i.e. document locations that have no document present but
> which contain subcollections with documents.**

So, you are certainly free to do the same in your app, assuming you have a backend that can use this API.

Comment: Doug, just to clarify, are you saying that the Node.js SDK's listDocuments() shows this missing nodes, while Python's firebase_admin might not?

Comment: I don't know, do you see a similar provided API?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no document at `/users/{userId}`, it won't show up in queries on `/users`. The Firestore console merely shows the `userId`, so that it can show the subcollection(s) you have under it.

The only way your client-side code can find out the existence of the `userId` path, is by querying the subcollection and then traversing the path from *that* `DocumentSnapshot` back up. This is a pretty kludgy workaround though, so I'd recommend always creating the `userId` document(s) if your use-case depends on being able to read them from `/users` later.